# How to select row values in pandas from one column based on these row values satisfying some condition in another column everywhere they appear

Tags: python, pandas

The title is confusing.

So, say I have a dataframe with one column, `id`, which occurs multiple times throughout my dataframe.  Then I have another column, lets call it `cumulativeOccurrences`.

How do I select all unique occurrences of id such that the other column fulfills a certain condition, say `cumulativeOccurrences > 20` for each and every instance of that `id`?

The beginning of the code is probably something like this:

```
dataframe.groupby('id')
```

But I can't figure out the rest.

Here is a sample small dataset that should return zero values:

```
id            cumulativeOccurrences
5494178       136
5494178        71
5494178        18
5494178        83
5494178        57
5494178       181
5494178        13
5494178        10
5494178        90
5494178      4484
```

Okay, here is the result I got after more muddling around:

```
res = df[['id','cumulativeOccurrences']].groupby(['id']).agg({'cumulativeOccurrences':[lambda x: all([e > 20 for e in x])]})
ids = res[res.cumulativeOccurrences['<lambda>']==True].index
```

This gives me a list of ids which fulfill the condition.  There probably is a better way than the list comprehension lambda function for the agg function, though.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add some data sample and desired output?

Answer (score 2):

First filter and then use [`DataFrameGroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.all.html):

```
res = (df['cumulativeOccurrences'] > 20).groupby(df['id']).all()
ids = res.index[res]
print (ids)
Int64Index([5494172], dtype='int64', name='id')
```

EDIT1:

First timings are for non sorted `id` and second for sorted.

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 10000000

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.random.randint(1000, size=N),
                   'cumulativeOccurrences':np.random.randint(19,5000,size=N)}, 
                   columns=['id','cumulativeOccurrences'])
print (df.head())
```

```
In [125]: %%timeit
     ...: res = (df['cumulativeOccurrences'] > 20).groupby(df['id']).all()
     ...: ids = res.index[res]
     ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 1.22 s per loop

In [126]: %%timeit
     ...: res = df[['id','cumulativeOccurrences']].groupby(['id']).agg({'cumulativeOccurrences':[lambda x: all([e > 20 for e in x])]})
     ...: ids = res[res.cumulativeOccurrences['<lambda>']==True].index
     ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 3.69 s per loop

In [127]: %timeit

In [128]: %%timeit
     ...: res = df['cumulativeOccurrences'].groupby(df['id']).agg(lambda x: all([e > 20 for e in x])) 
     ...: ids = res.index[res]
     ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 3.63 s per loop
```

---

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 10000000

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.random.randint(1000, size=N),
                   'cumulativeOccurrences':np.random.randint(19,5000,size=N)}, 
                   columns=['id','cumulativeOccurrences']).sort_values('id').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df.head())
```

```
In [130]: %%timeit
     ...: res = (df['cumulativeOccurrences'] > 20).groupby(df['id']).all()
     ...: ids = res.index[res]
     ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 795 ms per loop

In [131]: %%timeit
     ...: res = df[['id','cumulativeOccurrences']].groupby(['id']).agg({'cumulativeOccurrences':[lambda x: all([e > 20 for e in x])]})
     ...: ids = res[res.cumulativeOccurrences['<lambda>']==True].index
     ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 3.23 s per loop

In [132]: %%timeit
     ...: res = df['cumulativeOccurrences'].groupby(df['id']).agg(lambda x: all([e > 20 for e in x])) 
     ...: ids = res.index[res]
     ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 3.15 s per loop
```

Conclusion - Sorting `id` and unique index can improve performance. Also data was tested in `0.20.3` version under `python 3`.

Comment: This filters for ids which have at least one value of cumulativeOccurences over 20.  I am trying to get it it to filter such that all cumulativeOccurences by a specific id are over 20.

Comment: Hey - this works, I will select it as the answer, thank you.  I wonder if there is any way to do this faster, as it is pretty slow for my dataset (of about 42 million).

Comment: Can you test `df = (df['cumulativeOccurrences'] > 20).groupby(df['id']).transform('all').astype('int')` ?

Comment: Sorry! This doesn't work as it gets rid of the original ids (and I can't figure out how to match them back with these results).  What I am really looking for as an output is a list or set of the ids that fulfill the condition.

Comment: so for my changed df `{136,71}` for first group ?

Comment: I really like the simplicity of your answer, but it takes about 50% more time than than the one I ended up with a bit earlier, and I don't know why.  It seems to do the same thing.

Comment: It is really interesting, so what about simplify your version? `res = df['cumulativeOccurrences'].groupby(df['id']).agg(lambda x: all([e > 20 for e in x]))`
`ids = res.index[res]` ?